# The trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty error with Ubuntu 16.04 and openJDK 11 docker container

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, openjdk-11

I am using a docker container to deploy/run my application, previously I was using `openjdk:11-slim` as the base image and everything was working fine.

Now due to some other requirement, I change base docker image to `ubuntu:xenial` and installed OpenJDK with apt-get, my docker image looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa -y
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
#.......other commands.....
```

My application starts successfully, but when my application call AWS s3 APIs it is giving below error

```
  com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1136)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1082)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4443)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4390)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.deleteObject(AmazonS3Client.java:2123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.deleteObject(AmazonS3Client.java:2108)
    at com.com.example.core.service.ExpertS3Service.deleteProfilePicture(ExpertS3Service.java:314)
    at com.com.example.core.service.profile.ExpertProfileService.deleteProfilePicture(ExpertProfileService.java:319)
    at com.com.example.core.service.profile.ExpertProfileService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$19dd4604.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.com.example.core.service.profile.ExpertProfileService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dc5e9c9.deleteProfilePicture(<generated>)
    at com.com.example.rest.ExpertProfileResources.deleteProfilePicture(ExpertProfileResources.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:408)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor953.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy167.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:625)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    ... 107 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:86)
    ... 123 common frames omitted
```

Is there any solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: Working fine with `ubuntu:bionic` base image